# having issue batch file to delete files and folders of a specified location

Tags: batch-file, command, command-prompt

Hi have written a batch file  to delete files and folders of a specified location
all is fine but the issue is that when there is no such F: drive in the machine then 
the batch file delete the content of the folder where it has been kept .
Can any one help to modify the batch file and to write a condition to check wether that drive is present or not

My  batch file

```
set folder="F:\PortalViewState"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
pushd "F:\PortalViewState" 2>nul &&( rmdir . /s /q & popd )||(echo Folder not present)
```

Change drive and active directory to the target folder, *if no failure, then* remove anything inside it (the folder can not be deleted as it is the active directory) and return to the previous active directory

Comment: Yes its working
Can you kindly help me to echo/ display msg if the drive doesn  not exsits

Comment: @user3567527, message included. Shows when the `pushd` command fails

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
pushd
set folder="F:\PortalViewState"
cd /d %folder% 2>nul
ECHO ERRORLEVEL=%errorlevel%
IF "%cd%"==%folder% (ECHO Switched to %folder%) ELSE (ECHO failed to switch to %folder%)
set folder="U:\sourcedir"
cd /d %folder% 2>nul
ECHO ERRORLEVEL=%errorlevel%
IF "%cd%"==%folder% (ECHO Switched to %folder%) ELSE (ECHO failed to switch to %folder%)
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

This shows you two ways.

The surrounding `pushd/popd` simply saves and restores my test directory.

The u:\sourcedir directory exists on my system, so I get errorlevel=0 and a `switched` message. F: does not exist, so I get an errorlevel=1 and `failed` message.

The `2>nul` suppresses the error message when the destination drive does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to `pushd %folder%`

read `help rd` and then, simply

```
rd /s /q "f:\portalviewstate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, check that it exists or not and act accordingly

```
if not exist %folder% goto :somepart
```